# Opening ExcelFiles Read-only with Xlwings

Tags: python, xlwings

I've started looking at xlwings for my excel manipulation as the power and speed of python is much different then VBA for what I am hoping to do. (or so I am told)

Reading through some of the xlwings documentation I couldn't see if there was a way to open an excel file as read-only. Sometime the file I want to open and either open by another application or user, so I cannot access the file because it is trying to open as read-write.

Is there a way with xlwings or another python library that I can open an file in read-only mode, read information from particular ranges, then close the file?

Comment: I've opened a feature request: https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/318

Comment: @FelixZumstein Thank you. I wasn't sure if it was something I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

What about making a copy of the file, reading that copy, then deleting that copy after? Alternatively, if you use openpyxl, you dont need to "open" the file since you  are reading the xml metadata of excel.

```
import openpyxl as xl
workbook = xl.load_workbook('path/to/file.xls')
worksheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name('worksheetname')
cell = worksheet.cell('A1')
```

All these should work without needing to actually open the file.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. Because this is not "opening" the file, does it mean that script should run faster? For example I am currently looping through a hundreds of files. In VBA this takes 15 minutes because it actually opens an instance of the excel file.

Comment: Yes - i recommend using openpyxl in this instance. it's doesnt require the operating system to spin up an excel instance every single time (which takes a long time). XLWings and VBA are usually used to "remote control" an excel instance but I would use it for reading and writing to excel files without the need to the "remote controlling" functionality.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I have a follow up question, but I know it a bit out of scope for this. Do you know how I could run a frozen instance of an openpyxl script? It seems py2exe does not work with it.

Comment: I havent used py2exe too much nor have I needed to. When I need to distribute a script to others, I create a python virtual environment. Virtual envs are essentially portable isolated python instances. You can transport it to another machine and run it on that machine. I package it all up in a folder with a launch script (usually a two line .bat file in Windows) to run the python script using the virtual environment's python instance. It's a simpler and more generalized setup because p2exe and similar could have dependency issues with certain packages.